# Microservices authorization what approach should i use?

Tags: authorization, microservices

I have discussions at work for authorization, and we have different opinions about what it should look like. I would like to ask StackOverflow community which approach is correct because I can't find myself.

We're creating a new project.
We will use:

- kong as a proxy
- keycloak as an identity provider.

The user in the application will create the resource. Let's call it workspace. The workspace will contain a different resource, and the depression will go deeper. Example URL:
`/workspace/123/resource-A/321/resource-C`

There are 2 approaches presented in my work:

- at the beginning of the URL there will always be a workspace as prefix and then kong will use the LUA scripts to ask the workspace microservice whether the logged-in user has access into it and then redirect the request to the microservice. Each microservice will also start its URL from the workspace because we need a workspace ID to verify access to resource-A. They propose this approach because they want to limit the number of requests to microservice workspace from places other than kong. Example URL: `/workspace/123/microservice-A/workspace/123/microservice-B`
- URL does not have dependencies from the workspace, kong will be responsible for the proxy and communications with kong, the microservice will directly ask the workspace microservice for access using a token that was provided by the proxy. Each microservice decides its own access. Url examples: `/resource-A`, `/resource-B`

The system will also have microservice not connected to the workspace, but there will be fewer of them.

Do you know any other approaches? Which of my approaches is the most correct?

Thanks for help

set4812

Comment: There are plenty of other approaches. What do you want from your described approach be mandatory presented in alternatives? I mean, is it possible to change how microservices are addressed or what kind of token is used or what service should issue the tokens?

Comment: Which of these approaches would you choose? As if you were to create enterprise applications, for example TODO. The user has workspaces in which and can create TODOs. One microservice contains the Workspace and the second TODO. The user wants to add another TODO to the list. Now how microservice should handle user authorization into this TODO? Should proxy do this or todo microservices ask workspace service?
Should TODO microservice get a request from URL `/todo/123` or `/workspace/123/todo/321`

Comment: I do not like the proxy solution, it terribly forces what the microservice addresses look like, in addition, on the microservice side you need to verify the authorization by taking the ID from the URL and comparing them with the resource in the database. Can you suggest other solutions that match the TODO case? I am open to suggestions and training.

Comment: Have you read about [JWT](https://jwt.io/) and how claims are utilized in there?

Comment: I know that I can save additional workspace data in JWT that the user has, but then the problem is taking care of tokens invalidation. The token can expire after 5 minutes and during this time the user can change a lot. Admin can change the owner of the workspace, and you must then validate these tokens. I want to find a point where authorization for workspace access should take place

Comment: let's look at TODO

- user own workspaces

- workspace owns todo-list

- todo-list owns todos
When a user wants to edit TODO sending request PATCH `/todo/123` proxy communicates with the identity provider and check authentication, when authentication is correct proxy pass request into todo microservice. Should TODO send a request into GET `/worspace/{workspaceId}` to check a user have access to this workspace? I need to find a place on how to handle checking workspace access from other microservices.

Comment: Now I understand what you're asking for. Take a look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255581/public-api-facade-with-micro-services) question. Looks like it covers your interest. So, taking into account that there are two approaches, you need to pick one that suits you the best.

Comment: Also, personally I would go with an API facade which checks authorization and only after that redirects request to particular microservice. API facade is a good way to have as a layer in any case, adds flexibility. And looks like you don't have it at the moment, according to the scheme you described.

Comment: I don't think we understand each other. I have an API Gateway that covers routing between microservice. Verifies if the user is logged in, in the absence of it redirects him to the login page. This looks like an API facade. What the API gateway does is authentication not authorization.

Comment: The TODO service that gets the request is 100% sure it has a logged-in user, the address has the todo ID that the user wants to see. Based on this ID, I can extract TODO database entities, extract the workspace id from the entity it belongs to, and ask microservice workspace whether the user has access to it. Then the client will call the request as GET `domain.com/todos/123`. The problem with this assumption is that many microservices will ask the workspace service whether the user has access to this resource.

Comment: Another approach is that the Gateway API based on the address is able to verify access to the root resource. The user sends the address `domain.com/workspaces/123/todos/123` sees that the address has workspaces, pulls out his ID, and asks the workspace service for access. When it has access, it sends a request to service `todo-service/workspaces/123/todo/123`. Then the TODO service must verify that the TODO entity from id 123 has the value workspace 123. In this case all microservices will have prefixed `/workspaces/`.

Comment: If I were to place the API facade, there would be another microservice, layers in the microservice? What would it look like?

Comment: @set4812 API gateway is responsible for both authentication and authorization and many common concerns for your internal microservices. if your case that microservice will communicate with other services you don't need an API gateway to so you can do it directly. one of the API gateway characteristics to compose two services in one API endpoint.